AT25SF081 SPI Flash device terminology
I have a third question on the AT25SF081 Flash Datasheet Table 1-1.
In the Table 1-1 there are the statements: “The on the SI pin is always latched in on the rising edge of SCK” and “The on the SO pin is always clocked out on the falling edge of SCK”.
For this reason, in the master controller Verilog, I tell the SI/SO pin to perform computation in a 'always @ (negedge clk)' block.
For example in this code:
module flash_status (
    input wire clk,            // System clock
    input wire start,          // Start signal to begin the read
    output reg [7:0] data_out, // Data read from flash
    output reg done,           // Done signal to indicate completion
    output reg CS,             // Chip Select (Active low)
    output reg SCK,            // SPI Clock (Mode 0)
    output reg SI,             // SPI MOSI (Master Output Slave Input)
    input wire SO              // SPI MISO (Master Input Slave Output)
);
    ...
    always @(negedge clk) begin
        case (state)
            ...
            SEND_OPCODE: begin
                if (bit_count_send == 0) begin
                    bit_count_send <= 7;
                end else begin
                    SI <= shift_reg[bit_count_send]; // Send MSB first
                    bit_count_send <= bit_count_send - 1;
                end

            end
            READ_DATA: begin
                if (bit_count_read == 0) begin
                    bit_count_read <= 7;
                end else begin
                    data_out[bit_count_read] <= SO; // Sample bit from SO
                    bit_count_read <= bit_count_read - 1;
                end
            end
        endcase
    end
    ...
endmodule

Just to re-iterate, I am trying to understand if latched in on the rising edge of SCK and clocked out on the falling edge of SCK are actually pretty much the same thing - i.e. latched in on the rising edge means that the SI data is sampled around mid point of it's cycle, after being clocked out at a falling edge of the previous cycle - and clocked out on the falling edge ends up meaning that the SO is is sampled during the rising edge?
Maybe also if there is some doc on the physics behind this that someone could link me, it would be much appreciated.

It is necessary to meet the timing requirements on the AT25SF081 device.  For the SI data input pin, refer to  Figure 13-1. Serial Input Timing, where it shows that the SI input pin is sampled on the rising edge of the SCK clock signal.  The diagram shows 2 timing parameters:

tDS: data input setup time
tDH: data input hold time

These times are relative to the rising edge of the clock (SCK).  Rather than thinking of this as the "mid point of it's cycle", it is best to think of it as sampling when the data is guaranteed to be stable.  The timing requirements set the precise definition.
The situation is similar for the SO data output pin; refer to Figure 13-2.   Your logic (your FPGA Verilog design) would sample the AT25SF081 SO output data pin near the rising edge of SCK.


some doc on the physics behind this

Look for resources on digital logic design.
